# Html5 websql how to insert xml to local db table without a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an XML variable which i got from a web server and i want to insert it to a local db table without looping (looping is very slow....) using jquery / javascript,

the code i am using now for insert is:

```
   $(xx).find("Customers").each(function () {
         var $this = $(this),
             CustID = $this.find("CustID").text(),
             CustName = $this.find("CustName").text(),
             City = $this.find("City").text(),
             PhoneNum = $this.find("PhoneNum").text()
         // guid = $this.find("guid").text(),
         //  postid = $this.find("postid").text(),
         //  url = $this.find("enclosure").attr('url');
         i++;
         db.transaction(function (tx) {
             tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Customers (CustID, CustName, City, PhoneNum) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', [CustID, CustName, City, PhoneNum]);
         });
     });
```

XX is an xml variable.

Does anyone have an example of that?

Thanks,

Comment: could you give some code that you are already using?

Comment: edited the main question with code